# Xbox One Controller Wired? For PC

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

1) The Microsoft XBox One Controller + Cable (Wireless or Wired) for Windows is on sale, about $20 cheaper than the normal Wireless Xbox One controller. From my understanding, it's literally just the normal wireless controller + wire.

However, I can't seem to find out if it's the newer 3.5mm one. On the Microsoft web store, they have 2 editions.

So is there a 3.5mm jack version of the controller that comes with the cable? Since it's cheaper, I want to pricematch, but I'm not sure if it even exists.

I ordered one from Walmart (after price matching) and it says it features a 3.5mm jack: http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/microsoft-xbox-controller-cable-for-windows/6000196488062

Just got it today, and it doesn't have the 3.5mm jack. It's the old one.

2) If I buy a normal wireless 3.5mm Xbox One Controller, can I plug it into my computer using *any* cheap micro USB cable, and will it require batteries or just power itself through the cable? That's the main reason I want the Xbox Controller with the wire, along with the price reduction.

3) Anyone have problems with the microUSB cable becoming loose? Reading that it happens frequently for the Xbox One controller.

Comment: What's the question for 1)?

Comment: Sorry, meant to ask if there's a 3.5mm jack version of the controller that comes with the cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the listing does not boast a headphone jack, I would go off on a limb and say no, it likely does not. I wouldn't even take the chance at ordering it and attempting to return it should it fail to have the jack.

You are better off purchasing a controller from a retail store [(Example listing)](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Official-Microsoft-Xbox-One-Black-Wireless-Controller-with-Built-in-Headphone-Jack-Refurbished/194144318) of your choice, in person so you can have an employee open the box and verify it does have a headphone jack and micro-usb port, then using the cable to plug it into your compatible computing machine.

And, Yes. So long as you get a Data & charging cable, not just a Charging cable, you should be alright.

HOWEVER, the Microsoft Official controllers are *well known* for shorting cheaper cables - even some manufacturer ones, losing bumpers, and killing the micro-USB ports. Additionally, should you manage to obtain a controller with a headphone jack, plus two support & power ports, those can also become loose and eventually just give up.

Comment: Hmm the one I got has the same box as the one in your listing. Doesn't say 3.5mm on the box on your listing, though. Was avoiding opening the box because of hassles with return... you think I should risk it and just check if it has 3.5mm?                                                            http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/microsoft-xbox-controller-cable-for-windows/6000196488062 that one has a different picture of the box (white) for the 3.5mm version.

Comment: How many days since you've purchased it? Did you retain the receipt?

Comment: Just bought it 2 days ago, got it today. Yes, receipt in hand.

Comment: I personally have never had any issues with Walmart so long as I have the receipt, and it has been less than 30 days from the purchase in question. Typically, I will return an item with the box open, and if all of the parts and packaging are there, I will get either an exchange, a Walmart credit, and on rare occasions a cash refund. If you are unsure, you should call your local Walmarts' customer service and ask if they accept open box electronic returns if the purchase was made in the last 24 hours, or 7 days should it not contain the jack.

Comment: Thanks bud, just to confirm, if I get a regular Xbox One controller, like this one http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/microsoft-wireless-controller-xbox-one/6000196417424 it should work, without the need for batteries, as long as I buy a generic Data & Charging MicroUSB to USB cable, correct?

Comment: Correct, if it has the micro-USB port. Typically, if it would work with your Samsung mobile computer, it would work with your Xbox One controller.